# SAP Approve and Reject Hours

Tags: methods, sapui5, abap, sap-hr

I am a beginner with ABAP programming and I do not have much experience with SAP GUI...

I am developing a Fiori application to approve and reject absences like the standard application "approve leave request". I wanted to access the "approve leave request" methods to analyze the code to implement my methods..

How can I do that? Which methods / BAPIs do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

In the Fiori Apps Library you can search for [Fiori apps delivered by SAP](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/).

With search term “approve leave request” you will find the following 2 apps:

- Approve Leave Requests
- Approve Leave Requests (Version 2)

Under tab “IMPLEMENTATION INFORMATION” you can expand “Configuration”.
There you will find the corresponding oData Services:

- /GBHCM/LEAVEAPPROVAL
- HCM_LEAVE_REQ_APPROVE_SRV

With transaction SEGW in the backend, you should be able, to navigate to their corresponding ABAP classes.
It might be, that in SEGW you have to skip the “_SRV” and just search for “HCM_LEAVE_REQ_APPROVE”.